# Break out of a forEach loop in JSP/JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a collection of objects which have some properties. A property can only be of two types either `Type1` and `Type2`.

All I want to do is to check if an object has a property of `Type1`.

I'm using the following code for that:

```
<c:set var="properties" value="${obj.getProperties()}"/>
<c:set var="hasPropertyOfType1" value="false"/>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${fn:length(properties) - 1}">
    <c:if test="${properties.get(i).isOfType1() eq true}">
        <c:set var="hasPropertyOfType1" value="true"/>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

The above code achieves what I want but is highly inefficient because the number of properties an object may have is quiet high.

So my question is how to break out of the forEach loop once I set the `hasPropertyOfType1` equal to `true`.

Some approaches I have in mind, which I don't know how to implement (or that they're even possible) are:

1: Add a condition to the forEach loop which will stop the loop.
2: Increment the index value inside the loop to a value greater than `fn:length(properties)`.
3: Use the break statement if possible.

I have searched a lot but still haven't been able to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you do the right thing and add a method `boolean isPropertyOfType1Present()` in your object?

Comment: @JBNizet That would have been the ideal case but unfortunately that code is not under my control and as far as I know not changeable at this point in time.

Comment: And can't you wrap it inside your own object, which would provide this method? Or simply compute it in the controller and add it as a request attribute? This is something that should be done in Java, not in JSTL.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree that this should be done in Java, but that will require a lot of effort when compared to adding a simple break statement. Moving forward I may be able to add the `isPropertyOfType1Present()` but as of now I want a temporary workaround.

Comment: @JBNizet isn't this bad practice since we're supposed to keep presentation code separate from our business logic?

Answer (score 0):

The JSTL tag is for iterating over a collection.
It's not intended to search through a collection.

also you can use `<c:choose>` with `<c:when>` and `<c:otherwise>`
here are an example .
and you can use many  too

```
<c:forEach 
      var="List"
      items="${requestScope.DetailList}" 
      varStatus="counter"
      begin="0">

      <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${List.someType == 'aaa' || 'AAA'}">
           <!-- continue -->
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
            Do something...     
         </c:otherwise>
      <c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
```

Wish i was helpful